# ｍBaaSでの値を配列に反映させたい

Tags: javascript

現在制作しているもの
➀日付・数字を入力してmBaaSに送る。
②mBaaSから値を引き抜き配列に入れる
③Chart.jsを使ってグラフに反映させる

monaca・mBaaSとの連携でシステムを作っています。
ｍBaaSから値を出す場合の方法を知りたい。

コード

```
// SDKの初期化
var ncmb = new NCMB(applicationKey, clientKey);

// ボタンが押されたときの処理
function pushButton() {
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value; // 金額
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value; // 日付

    alert(message); // アラートで表示

    // 保存先クラスの生成
    var MessageClass = ncmb.DataStore("MessageClass");

    // クラスインスタンスの生成
    var messageClass = new MessageClass();

    // データを設定
    messageClass.set("message", message);
    messageClass.set("day", day);

    // データを保存し、結果を処理する
    messageClass.save()
        .then(function(savedObject) {
            // 保存成功時の処理
            console.log("保存に成功しました。", savedObject);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // 保存失敗時の処理
            console.error("保存に失敗しました。エラー:", error);
        });
}
</script>


</head>

<body>
 <a href="#" onclick="history.back()">前のページへ戻る</a>
    <center>
       <img src="hi.png">
<br>
<label for="day2">日付:</label>
<input id="day" type="month" name="example">
<br>
<label for="salary">金額:</label>
<input type="text" id="message" name="salary"
    oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />



<button onclick="pushButton();">送信</button>
</center>

結果：<span id="item"></span>

<div style="width:350px;" >
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>

 <script>
    // ページが読み込まれたらグラフを描画
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
      var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // グラフの種類：折れ線グラフを指定
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          // x軸の各メモリ
          labels: ['４月', '５月', '６月', '７月', '８月', '９月'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: '最高気温(度）',
              data: [27, 26, 31, 25, 30, 22],
              borderColor: "#ec4343",
              backgroundColor: "#00000000"
            },
            {
              label: '最低気温(度）',
              data: [18, 21, 24, 22, 21, 19],
              borderColor: "#2260ea",
              backgroundColor: "#00000000"
            }
          ],
        },
```

気温などは、サンプルです。dataの中の配列にニフクラのデータを反映させたいです。

試したこと
`結果：<span id="item"></span>`に反映させようとして

```
function MessageClass() {
/** mobile backend に取得する **/
// 保存先クラスの生成
var MessageClass = ncmb.DataStore("MessageClass");
// 取得処理
Omikuji.fetchAll()
.then(function(objects){
```

をしました。入力したデータがｍBaaSのカラム名messageに入っています。

すみませんが、どなたか教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/cllglagodgnvew) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)